# Cannot restore from UNC path SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am triyng to restore a database using script pointing from a UNC path but for some reason it is giving the "cannot access backup device" which normally has something to do with permissions error. However, replace the UNC path with C and the script works.
I checked permmissions and the folder where the backup is stored, Network  service has full acesss. Also Also if I look at the "Log on as" option for SQL in services Network Service is selected.

So I am not exactly sure where I should give permissions so allow a UNC path to be permitted to backup too.

Would love the help.
Thank you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo.].[restore]
 (
  @path nvarchar(300)
)
AS
  ALTER DATABASE [Adworks] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
  RESTORE DATABASE [Adworks] FROM  DISK = @path WITH REPLACE
   ALTER DATABASE Adworks SET MULTI_USER;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following the steps in this blog [Restore Database from a UNC path – Why SSMS doesn’t show network drives/paths in the restore wizard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_scratchpad/archive/2014/03/11/restore-database-from-an-unc-path-why-ssms-doesn-t-show-network-drives-paths-in-restore-wizard.aspx)

1. Created a directory in the remote computer
2. Shared it with “Everyone” – Actually We just need to make sure that the service account under which SQL is running is having permissions to access the shared folder).
3. Enabled XP_CMDSHELL by issuing `sp_configure 'XP_CMDSHELL' , 1` reconfigure with override
4. Mapped the network drive in the same session as SQL is running by issuing `xp_Cmdshell ‘net use p: \\csm1\bkp_test’`
5. Now executed `xp_fixeddrives` with argument 1
6. The restore wizard now shows network drives

He then goes on to make it an automated process if this is for a regular task rather than a once off.

Comment: I wasn't using a wizard, I was actually pasting the path in the script, but I will do what you say

Comment: On Step 2- " You mean that Network Service should have full access to that folder right?

Comment: Yes, he does state that it is just the Service Account that SQL is running under needs to have permissions.

Comment: Firstly, my user NEtwork Service aleady has full access to that folder. However, I am not trying to do it in the wizard I am actually trying to get it operating thru code. Will this solve this as well?

Comment: I would just like to restore from the path I passed to my  store proc I posted above

Comment: Well then it should just be   RESTORE DATABASE FROM DISK = \\server_name\shared_drive\backup_file_name.bak    and apart from the permissions it should just work

Comment: have you done this recently? I am walking thru this step by step however, when I get to step 5 and execute fixed drives, nothing comes up, the network path is not showed in the restore GUI. even thou step 4 executed sucessfully

Comment: No, I haven't done this recently, in fact I usually copy the .bak file to the SQL server local drive when restoring.

Comment: It works, Problem was I had to change Sql log on as to a user with network access.